# one liner increment of variable value in text file using perl

Tags: file, perl, numbers, increment

I have variable in file of perl program. I only want to increase value vertically position of `$[0] as $[1] $[2]`, as each $[0] variable right now have base 64 to utf-8 values.

I only want to change $[0] to increase value until end of file.

I tried command of perl as mentioned

```
perl -pi -e 's/U[0](\d+)[0].($1+1)/e' 25k.list
```

> syntax error at -e line 1, near "](" Unmatched [ in regex; marked by
>   <-- HERE in m/ <-- HERE ,/ at -e line 1.

Added:

some data in file:

```
$U[0] = "\data1\fileloader.ini";
$U[0] = "\data1\data2\crame\crame.ini";
$U[0] = "\data1\data2\data3\files\setup.exe";
$U[0] = "\data1\data2\data3\data4\WINDOWS\win.ini";
```

What I want, increase $U[from 0, untill it no longer occur], it should be:

```
$U[0] = "\data1\fileloader.ini";
$U[1] = "\data1\data2\crame\crame.ini";
$U[2] = "\data1\data2\data3\files\setup.exe";
$U[3] = "\data1\data2\data3\data4\WINDOWS\win.ini";

only affecting $U[ ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `s///` expression that works for this case is:

```perl
s/\$U\[0\]/"\$U[".$c++."]"/ge
```

This means:  Replace every occurence of `$U[0]` with `$U[n]`, `n` being the next integer starting from `0`.

Please read: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html about `s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/`.

Comment: Shorter: `s/\$U\[\K0(?=\])/$c++/ge`

Comment: If you used single quotes instead of double quotes, you wouldn't need to escape the `$` in the replacement string.

Answer (score 1):

The "Syntax error" comes from the fact that your regexp is missing the `/` which should separate search pattern from replacement part. Additionally you want to execute the replacement part and I think the `[]` are meatn literally. So my best guess is, your s/p/r/ should be: `s/U\[0\](\d+)/"U[0]".($1+1)/e`

Comment: I tired, even tweaked it but still it's not working

Comment: "still it's not working" is not a proper error description. You even gave no example input and output.

Comment: data in file:
$U[0] = "\data1\fileloader.ini";
$U[0] = "\data1\data2\crame\crame.ini";
$U[0] = "\data1\data2\data3\files\setup.exe";
$U[0] = "\data1\data2\data3\data4\WINDOWS\win.ini";
command:
perl -pi -e 's/U\[0\](\d+)/"U[0]".($1+1)/e' adjustedlist.txt
problem:
now after using this command, $U[0] does not increase.

Comment: First of all you did not use the regex I gave. The backslashes seem to be missing. Then `"\data1\fileloader.ini"` for sure is not a number, so nothing that can be increased. Lastely: Please enhance you original post so that example input and output can properly be read.

Comment: please check and provide solution

Comment: No. Sorry. I'm not here to provide a solution. But I can give you a hint. Currently you are searching for `U[0]` followed by digits. But you only need to find `U[0]` or better `$U[0]` which can be achieved with `/\$U\[0\]/`. Then, in the replacement part, you need to use a variable defined outside, which you increase with every step. I hope this is enough to get you going.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do what you want.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $x = 0;

while (<DATA>) {
  s/U\[0]/'U[' . $x++ . ']'/e;
  print;
}

__DATA__
$U[0] = "\data1\fileloader.ini";
$U[0] = "\data1\data2\crame\crame.ini";
$U[0] = "\data1\data2\data3\files\setup.exe";
$U[0] = "\data1\data2\data3\data4\WINDOWS\win.ini";
```

The output I get is:

```
$U[0] = "\data1\fileloader.ini";
$U[1] = "\data1\data2\crame\crame.ini";
$U[2] = "\data1\data2\data3\files\setup.exe";
$U[3] = "\data1\data2\data3\data4\WINDOWS\win.ini";
```

Like the other answers, I've basically made three fixes here.

- Stop `[0]` being interpreted as a character class.
- Correct the syntax of your `s/.../.../` expression.
- Ignore `$1` and use an incrementing variable for the replacement integer.